# Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'Wsdl2CodeProxyDelegate'

Tags: ios, swift

When i call the Wsdl2CodeProxyDelegate method it showing  **Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'Wsdl2CodeProxyDelegate'** error I implemented all required method which are be @required.But i don't know why i am getting this error.Can you please help for solving this issue.Thanks in[image: I am Getting Below error,How can i solve??] advance

Comment: can you add implemented methods names

Comment: Yes @HarshalBhavsar .but still i am getting same error.The files are in objective-c.

Comment: func proxyRecievedError(ex: NSException!, inMethod method: String!) {
        
    }
    
    func proxydidFinishLoadingData(data: AnyObject!, inMethod method: String!) {
        
    } These two methods i added and call the delegate method.i don't know y i am getting this error

Answer (score 0):

As i can see on following URL

[http://www.wsdl2code.com/](http://www.wsdl2code.com/pages/example.aspx)

you need to implement following methods, have you implemented the following methods.

```
func proxyRecievedError(ex: NSException, InMethod method: String) {
}
```

and

```
func proxydidFinishLoadingData(data: AnyObject, InMethod method: String) {
}
```

Comment: i added above methods still i am facing the same issue .@Harshal Bhavsar